# EU Data Retention Directive and the Draft Investigatory Powers Bill 2015

Tags: legal

Was the EU Data Retention Directive ever transcribed into English law?

If so, the Draft Investigatory Powers Bill 2015 would appear to be somewhat moot?

Comment: This site focuses on technical question requiring technical expertise. Legal questions will most likely find a better audience on the [law.se] StackExchange site.